# SumIf statements - complicated criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Here's my story on this. The code below will count all rows starting at row 84 that have "1" in column R, something that begins with a "B" in column K, **and** either "98 (macro)" or "98" in column L.

```
B_black = Application.Sum(Application.SumIfs(Range("R84:R" & LastRow), Range("R84:R" & LastRow), "1", Range("K84:K" & LastRow), "B*", Range("L84:L" & LastRow), Array("98 (macro)", "98")))
```

Instead of counting the number of rows with that criteria, I need it to essentially sum the quantities of the matches in column R. Before, the value in column R would either be "1" or null. Now, it can be null or 1-9. How can I do this?

**EDIT**: 
I'm going to have dozens of these statements. I already have them all written out. I'm hoping I can just make a small change in each statement to count the quantities in column R in the rows that meet the criteria.

Comment: remove the `Range("R84:R" & LastRow), "1"` part?

Comment: Right, but then once those rows are identified, I need to get the sum of the quantities in column R.

Comment: If you remove the part I showed the formula will do what you want.  b

Comment: By not limiting the sumifs to only those that have `1` in column R you will sum all the values in column R.

Comment: @ScottCraner, taking out the `Range("R84:R" & LastRow), "1"` part did the trick! Do you want to add it as an answer so I can mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *sum the values* in column **R** rather than just *count rows* then:

```
Sub Robby()
    Dim B_black As Long, n As Long, i As Long
    B_black = 0
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 83 To n
        If Left(Cells(i, "K").Value, 1) = "B" And (Cells(i, "L").Value = 98 Or Cells(i, "L").Value = "98 (macro)") Then
            B_black = B_black + Cells(i, "R").Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

There is no requirement to use worksheet functions.

**EDIT#1:**

If you already have equations in worksheet cells, you are already 75% there.

Say we are using:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1 & B2,F1:J16,2,FALSE)
```

in a cell.  To execute this in VBA, code something like:

```
Sub DoItInAMacro()
    Dim s As String
    s = Evaluate("=VLOOKUP(B1 & B2,F1:J16,2,FALSE)")
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do what I want using the same type of structure I have now? I'm going to have to set up dozens of these, and I feel like it would be easier to manage and maintain to do it more similarly to how my current method.

Comment: @Robby Do you already have the equations as worksheet formulas??

Comment: I do. I was hoping I could just make a minor edit to each equation to do what I wanted.

Comment: @Robby  see my **EDIT#1**